# Where are screen recording saved in macOS Mojave by default?

Tags: mojave, screen-capture

I made a screen recording as mentioned in this Apple's [support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208721). Can someone let me know where are the screen recordings are saved after pressing "Done" and with what name it is saved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Shift-Cmd-5</kbd> again to bring up the onscreen controls
- Click on Options
- Currently defined target for recordings is displayed on the top of the Options menu

Answer (score 2):

They save to where you have set in the Options menu after opening the Screen Recording function with  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>5</kbd>

The file is named "Screen Recording *date* at *time*.mov"

[image]